# Why is it faster to SELECT my logical CASE field into a new temp table as opposed to UPDATing the original temp table to SET the field?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, update, heap, query-performance

I have a pretty large temp table (about 4.5 million rows) with no indexes, so it's stored in a heap. Let's call it `#TempTable1`.

`#TempTable1` has a BIT field called ToInclude which is set in a subsequent UPDATE query and uses a CASE statement based on other fields in the table to set the value appropriately.

The `UPDATE #TempTable1 SET ToInclude = CASE...` query takes a full minute to execute. But instead of doing an UPDATE, if I `SELECT *, CASE...END AS ToInclude INTO #TempTable2` that only takes about five seconds, even though it's the same exact CASE statement I'm using in either query.

Here are the TIME and IO statistics for each instance.

**UPDATE Query (#TempTable1):**
[image: Update Query]

**SELECT *, CASE...END AS ToInclude INTO #TempTable2 Query:**
[image: SELECT *, CASE...END AS ToInclude Query]

I see in the first case (for the UPDATE query) SQL uses the Worktable. I've never heard of this concept before, but more so I'm interested in why it goes this route. It looks like in the first case, it takes an extra 15 million logical reads too, not sure why.

Also, I've tested this multiple times, switching the order of which query I run first, and dropping `#TempTable1` between each test, to ensure I'm not experiencing a difference in memory caching. These results continue to be repeatable.

Comment: My guess is that you end up with some kind of halloween-protection. I.e., SQL Server need to protect itself from modifying a row, making the row move to somewhere else and it need to make sure that it now don't update that same row once again. Perhaps having a clustered index on the table will make a difference, that would be my first thing to explore, if not else just as a test...

Comment: I usually like to index my tables if they're going to be re-used, but unfortunately I've found that I get the best performance with the operations that this table undergoes for it's lifespan by not indexing it. (I.e. In this case, it takes longer to create the index on the table than the time the index saves on the subsequent queries executed against the table.)

Comment: Also, you might be right. I just re-read how SQL server handles the Halloween problem, and it seems like it introduces an extra step into the execution plan for Eager Spool. I re-ran my test case for the UPDATE query and it does have the Eager Spool step in the execution plan (with a fairly significant amount of time tied to it) whereas my SELECT INTO query does not have that step, otherwise the execution plans are pretty similar.